# How do I run Packet Tracer 6.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.3?

Tags: 12.04

I'm trying to install Packet Tracer according to answers about **13.04.**, but it doesn't work.

```
:/home/krzysztof/Downloads# ./CPT601

bash: ./CPT601: cannot execute binary file

:/home/krzysztof/Downloads#
```

This is what I get instead.

I need it to work!

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
sudo sh ./CPT601
```

Or

```
sudo bash CPT601
```